# Sort by case in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a domain "Notification"

```
{
  _id: 1
  is_action: false,
  user:[{
        user_id: 5,
        status: "R"
    },
    {
        user_id: 8,
        status: "U"
    }],
    priority:1    
},
{
  _id: 2
  is_action: true,
  user:[{
        user_id: 5,
        status: "U"
    },
    {
        user_id: 8,
        status: "U"
    }],
    priority:1    
}
```

My query to find notification where user_id = 5   ------

```
db.notifications.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$user"},
    {$match:{
        "user.user_id":5,
        is_action: false
    }},
    {$sort:{priority:1}}
])
```

But I need to sort the above query according to the following condition

```
if(status == "U"){
    Sort by "priority"
}else{
    Sort by "_id"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to create a new field, e.g.

`{
     $project:
      {
         otherfield: 1,
         sortField: {
             $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$status","U" ] }, 
                       then: "$priority", 
                       else: "$_id" }
           }
      }
  }`

And then sort this field.

P.S. $cond is a new operator in MongoDB version 2.6 and above

Comment: You can try to use a MongoDB GUI, it may solve your problem much more easily. Try http://mongobooster.com, it is free for non-commercial.